# How can I modify a field or a type in all indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 1.5.2. I created many indexes, and every index has a type and different fields. I want to modify the name of a field that exists in many indexes. How can I do it? The same thing for a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly no.

You cannot change the name or type of the field once an index is created.

They have added some support for renaming fields in [Elasticsearch 5.2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rename-processor.html)

The only option is to recreate the index from the old index. [ES-reindex](https://github.com/geronime/es-reindex) tool might help you.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help.